# Simple Java Operator Contradiction

Tags: java, operators

This might be too little information... but why is this working opposite as I expect?

```
                if (indSTime[t] <= monthTotal) {

                    Log.d("indSTime", String.valueOf(indSTime[t++]));
                    Log.d("monthTotal", String.valueOf(monthTotal));

                    NewRate = Double.valueOf(indSRate[s]);
                    indApr[o] = NewRate;
                }
```

It is working as Greater than or equal to.  NOT Less than or equal to the Month total.

I have the "indSTime" set to 4.  So Logcat in Eclipse starts logging the two variables like this.

```
4, 4
4, 5
4, 6
4, 7
```

etc...

it seems it should be

```
4 ,1
4, 2
4, 3
4, 4
```

and STOP.

I know I didn't add much code above?  is there something right in front of me that I am missing?  Or what can cause this?

Comment: what is the value of t,s,o ? Can u explain a bit more your question?

Comment: "I have the indSTime set to 4." -- How can you have an array set to 4? Do you mean the length of it? Is this code in a loop somewhere?

Comment: Well the array in this instance is a length of 1.  And it is set to 4, that is, the one value in the array.

Comment: t s an o are all counter's.  In this example, they are all length of 1.  I am looping through, in this case, banks or financial institutions.  In the example above, I am testing just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's logging entirely reasonable things. Look at your pairings:

Actual:

```
indSTime=4, monthTotal=4
indSTime=4, monthTotal=5
indSTime=4, monthTotal=6
indSTime=4, monthTotal=7
```

Expected:

```
indSTime=4, monthTotal=1
indSTime=4, monthTotal=2
indSTime=4, monthTotal=3
indSTime=4, monthTotal=4
```

In all of the *actual* cases, `indSTime` is less than or equal to `monthTotal`, exactly as your code suggests.

In your *expected* output, you've shown three cases where `indSTime` is *greater than* `monthTotal`.

So, either you actually *wanted* the opposite operator, or you've been confused by your logging, or possibly both. Unfortunately as you haven't shown any context here, it's impossible to say exactly where the problem is - but it's definitely not Java itself.

Comment: Yes yes.  My brain was in a knot. I was thinking opposite, not my code. This was rightfully voted down.  Have you ever looked for the milk in the fridge and it's right in front of you?  That is what happened here.

Answer (score 3):

4 *is* less-than-or-equal-to 4, 5, 6 and 7.

4 is definitely *not* less-than-or-equal-to 1, 2 or 3.

Why do you think it should be the opposite?